# How to downgrade NPM package via CLI to an older minor version with using tilde version tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependency-management

I have **Typescript version ^3.7.4 installed as a devDependency** in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-awesome-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  }
}
```

I want to **downgrade Typescript locked to the minor version 3.5, but with the newest patch versions applied**. So the correct [SemVer](https://semver.org/) version tag would be with the tilde character, so **~3.5.0** in this case.

**Which NPM command to run for this downgrade?**

I have tried running `npm i -D typescript@~3.5.0`, however after the installation `package.json` has `"typescript": "^3.5.3"` instead of `"typescript": "~3.5.3"` that I was expecting...

*Using NPM version 6.9.0 and Node 12.5.0.*

Comment: Add `-E` per https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: @jonrsharpe didn't work as `--save-exact` results in an exact version: `"typescript": "3.5.3"`

Comment: I would suggest to uninstall typescript and then install it again with the desired version.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth yes I could install with tilde version tag by editing `package.json` by hand, but this question is about downgrading with tilde versioning by running a NPM command. If there is no such command available, there is probably a bug with NPM or just bad design.

Comment: As a workaround, you could use `yarn` instead (`yarn add typescript@~3.5.3`), which doesn't exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way around this from some quick tests. I did find some issues around the topic though, so perhaps it is a bug. I would suggest that you open an issue on the new [npm/cli](https://github.com/npm/cli) repo as these issues are all on an archived repository so maybe they have been forgotten slightly.

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19585
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19211

Comment: Thanks @cdimitroulas for digging into the NPM repos. I've now filed an issue: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/636